# Why would processes in multiprocessing.Pool stop working / spawning?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

For some reason, at the start of the script's execution (macOS), I have 8 processes in multiprocessing Pool spawned and working, but in several minutes after the start, there is only 1 process working left.

I have this code (it's way bigger than that, but it'll explain the picture):

```
def GetStatesDataset(dataset):
    df_states = pd.read_csv(dataset)
    return df_states

def UploadDataFrameToBigQuery(table_name, prefix_name, project_id, if_exists, df):
    table_name = table_name + prefix_name
    pd.DataFrame.to_gbq(df,
                        table_name,
                        project_id=project_id,
                        if_exists=if_exists)

def InitGetDataFromGCP(data, prefix):
    client = storage.Client()
    files = []
    blobs = client.list_blobs(data, prefix=prefix)
    for blob in blobs:
        files.append(f'{data}/{blob.name}')
    return files

def GetDataFromGCP(file):
    fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem() # GCP's Google Cloud Storage (GCS) File System (FS)
    with fs.open(file, 'r') as f:
        # Reading json into Pandas DataFrame
        gcs_data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
        data = [gcs_data] if isinstance(gcs_data, dict) else gcs_data
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    df = pd.merge_asof(df,
                      df_states,
                      left_on="start_time",
                      right_on="state_reached_at",
                      by="car_id",
                      direction="backward")
    UploadDataFrameToBigQuery(table_name, prefix_name, project_id, if_exists, df)
    
    logging.info(str(multiprocessing.current_process()) + 'Finished: execution time: ' + str(exec_time))

#######################

df_states = GetStatesDataset('gs://link-to-my.csv')

dataset_name = 'one'
prefix_name = 'two'

# config for uploading data to BigQuery

table_name = 'one-two.'
project_id = 'one-two-three'

if_exists = 'append'


def main():
    files = InitGetDataFromGCP(dataset_name, prefix_name)

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        pool.map(GetDataFromGCP, files)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Since I'm logging everything, I can see all the processes at the start (everything's working fine):

```
2020-08-29 15:55:13,957 <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-8' parent=1420 started daemon>Finished: execution time: 22.53874
2020-08-29 15:55:15,947 <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-7' parent=1420 started daemon>Finished: execution time: 23.259828000000002
2020-08-29 15:55:17,219 <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-3' parent=1420 started daemon>Finished: execution time: 8.758934000000004
2020-08-29 15:55:19,094 <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-6' parent=1420 started daemon>Finished: execution time: 7.409976
2020-08-29 15:55:21,755 <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-6' parent=1420 started daemon>Finished: execution time: 0.25443099999999674
```

but after some time I get this:

```
2020-08-29 16:24:28,494 <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=1420 started daemon>Finished: execution time: 10.398635000000013
2020-08-29 16:24:36,077 <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=1420 started daemon>Finished: execution time: 4.782628999999929
2020-08-29 16:24:40,220 <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=1420 started daemon>Finished: execution time: 1.1638890000000401
2020-08-29 16:24:44,032 <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=1420 started daemon>Finished: execution time: 1.519871999999964
2020-08-29 16:24:50,449 <SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-1' parent=1420 started daemon>Finished: execution time: 3.1979730000000473
```

I also can confirm that there is only 1 process working by looking at my CPU activity. There are 8 Python processes spawned, but only 1 is close to 100%. I am new to multiprocessing, maybe I don't know what I'm doing, but I want all the 8 workers to perform tasks until my "files" end.

Comment: On a quick look I don't see any major issues with this. Although I have a fair amount of experience with multiprocessing, I have not used `multiprocessing.Pool` yet. Are you aware of [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor)? It seems to suit your use-case quite well and will give you a higher-level abstraction.

Comment: I actually started learning Multiprocessing from concurrent.futures but wasn't able to get it to work somehow (and I wanted to gain more control of the multiprocessing, so I switched to multiprocessing.Pool). And I seem to solve my problem with specifying `chunksize=1` in `pool.map`. Just a few tests and I think that I'm going to answer my own question here.

Comment: in that case you may want to post it as an answer and accept it once you can. That way, the question won't be listed as "unanswered" and other people running into the same issue could benefit from your solution.

Comment: yes, of course, I'll do it after I've done some testing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so obvious. I just needed to specify a *chunksize*. Since I have almost 17000 files that I need to process, one file at a time, *chunksize=1* seems to work like a charm:

```
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        result = pool.map(GetDataFromGCP, files, chunksize=1)
```